# Puppeteer keeps getting TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 80000 ms exceeded

Tags: node.js, express, puppeteer, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to scrape any web page passed as into the scrape function, but no matter the timeout set at page.goto(), I keep getting a timeout error, if set to 0, the app just keeps waiting.

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const MYPORT = process.env.PORT || 4001;


const app = express();
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const scrape = async (url) => {
    var body;
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true,
            args: ['--no-sandbox'],
            timeout: 0
        });
        console.log('Browser launched');
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log('Page opened');
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 3 * 60000 });
        await page.waitForSelector('body', {waitUntil: 'load'})
        console.log('Link opened');
        await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 3 * 60000});
        page.$eval('html', bdy => {
            console.log(bdy);
            body = bdy.innerHTML;
        });
        browser.close();
        return body;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

scrape('http://google.com');
```

Please, what am I doing wrong?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have overcomplicated a bit the timeout-waitfor part of your script. I advise the following changes:

0. If you are not sure what causes a timeout you should set `headless: false` so you can see on the UI what goes wrong, you can open the browser console etc.
1. Don't set timeouts until the script does what you want with `waitForSelector`-s. I removed them from your script.
2. If you are not interested in every network events (especially not in analytics and tracking requests), but you only need DOM, then use `waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'` rather than `load` or the most strict `networkidle2`! See what is the exact differrence between them in the docs: [[link]](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.0&show=api-pagegotourl-options)
3. Do not `waitForNavigation` after you've already waited for a selector. That was the main reason why your script failed: once `<body>` appeared in the DOM, you asked puppeteer to wait until a navigation is finished, but you didn't navigate at this time: you were already on the page. Keep in mind:

> `page.waitForNavigation` resolves when the page navigates to a new URL or reloads. It is useful for when you run code which will indirectly cause the page to navigate. [[source]](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v4.0.0&show=api-pagewaitfornavigationoptions)

4. Your `page.$eval` was lacking its async nature, while it should be async always. Anyway the `innerHTML` of `<body>` can be retrieved more simply with an: `await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, await page.$('body'))`.

```js
const scrape = async url => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      args: ['--no-sandbox']
    })
    console.log('Browser launched')
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    console.log('Page opened')
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' })
    await page.waitForSelector('body')
    console.log('Link opened')
    const body = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, await page.$('body'))
    console.log(body)
    browser.close()
    return body
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and for the solution. I ran the code on Heroku and it worked well, but I get a 256 error in Chromium on my local machine. But I consider the question resolved and I will have to find a way to resolve the 256 error. Thank you once more!

Comment: I see, I suppose if it worked on Heroku you have already added the required build pack: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-heroku. Error 256 is related to GPU, if you've fixed the code `headless: true` can be re-enabled again (it does not needed on Heroku). If you are still facing the problem the `--disable-gpu` launch arg may help.

Comment: Yes I already added the build pack. I suppose there's nothing I can do about the 256 error then since the `--disable-gpu` flag does not work for my machine, so I'll just run the code from Heroku whenever required. Thank you so much for the insights, they are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error on circleci because I didn't setup **proxy setting** on puppeteer args.

So that test url is unreachable.

Here is my solution for it.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({         
  args: ['--proxy-server=http://your-proxy-url:port'], 
});
```