# Webscraping TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, platformio

I'm trying to extract some table from a company website using puppeteer.

But I don't understand why the browser open Chromium instead my default Chrome, which then lead to "TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded", not let me enough time to use CSS Selector. I can't find a document referencing this.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://www....com');
//search tearm
  await page.type("#search_term","Brazil");

  //await page.screenshot({path: 'sc2.png'});
  //await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Pages that take longer than 30 seconds to load are either super heavy or blocking you, so this is missing a [mcve] of the actual URL. Avoid timeout 0 as many answers suggest--try for 4-5 minutes at the most. If a site can't load in that time, it never will. Using headless: false is a good way to debug these issues. If it loads headfully, then the issue reduces to [Why does headless need to be false for Puppeteer to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818869/why-does-headless-need-to-be-false-for-puppeteer-to-work).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Puppeteer, is Chromium based by default.
If you wish to use Chrome instead you have to specify the executable path through the [`executablePath` launch parameter](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/README.md#default-runtime-settings). But to be honest, most of the time, there is no point to do so.

```
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath: `/path/to/Chrome`,
    //...
});
```

---

There is no correlation between `TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded` and the use chromium rather it is more likely that your target url isn't (yet) available.

> page.goto will throw an error if:
>
> - there's an SSL error (e.g. in case of self-signed certificates).
> - target URL is invalid.
> - the timeout is exceeded during navigation.
> - the remote server does not respond or is unreachable.
> - the main resource failed to load.

By default, the maximum navigation timeout is 30 seconds. If for some reason, your target url requires more time to load (which seems unlikely), you can specify a `timeout: 0` option.

```
await page.goto(`https://github.com/`, {timeout: 0});
```

---

As Puppeteer will not throw an error when an HTTP status code is returned...

> page.goto will not throw an error when any valid HTTP status code is returned by the remote server, including 404 "Not Found" and 500 "Internal Server Error".

I usually check the [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) to make sure I'm not encountering any [404 Client error responses Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400).

```
let status = await page.goto(`https://github.com/`);
status = status.status();
if (status != 404) {
    console.log(`Probably HTTP response status code 200 OK.`);
    //...
};
```

I'm flying blind here as I don't have your target url nor more information on what you're trying to accomplish.

You should also give the [puppeteer api documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md) a read.

Comment: I got this error on circleci because I didn't setup proxy setting on puppeteer args. So that test url is unreachable. Here is my solution for it. `const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--proxy-server=http://your-proxy-url:port'],
});` Reference => https://stackoverflow.com/a/72540678/2853544

Comment: `timeout: 0` (infinity) is too much. I'd set this to something like 5 minutes. If it doesn't load in 5 minutes, you'll want to know about it so there's a clear error report and option for the script to retry rather than suppressing the error and letting the script hang forever, which is hard to debug.

Comment: @ggorlen how can you check if it doesn't load in 5 minutes?

Comment: @NamLee `try`/`catch` works.

Answer (score 6):

Below approach works for me. Try adding this following "1 Liner" to your code.

The `setDefaultNavigationTimeout` method allows you to define the timeout of the tab and expects as first argument, the `value in milliseconds`. Here a value of `0 means` an `unlimited amount of time`. Since I know my page will load up someday.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  // Add the below 1 line of code
  page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
  // follows the rest of your code block
})();
```

Comment: setDefaultNavigationTimeout has return type void, no need to `await`

Comment: If the page doesn't load in a few minutes, it never will. The error is good, it allows you to deal with the underlying problem rather than suppress it and go into an infinite loop. See [this post](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#using-infinite-timeouts) for details. If you are going to extend the timeout, use something like `page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(10 * 60 * 1000)` (10 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

For me this error was because the css selector was very long, I have tried many times for different web scrapers, just shortening the css selector fixed my issue.
For example: this was giving error:

> body > main > div.col-lg-9 > div.row.gx-2.adobe_bold.h3 > div.col-md-4
> a

but after shortening it like below the error is gone.

> div.row.gx-2.adobe_bold.h3 > div.col-md-4 a

Answer (score -3):

I can fix this doing changes in node_modules node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/util/Deferred.js:27 here you can figure out the condition of when the error is trow

Answer (score -4):

To be honest I was tired of This TimeOut error. After trying many options here  is what worked for me:

Warning => you are about to change the source code. Do at your own risk :)

Open source code in node_modules:
go to >
puppeteer-core > lib > cjs > puppeteer > common > Frame.js  (file path)
Go to line 282
Change from "trow error" to "console.log(error)"

Now you console logging it to the server instead of crashing your application.

At the end of the day we are looking mostly for Scraping and automation and not dealing with Timeouts crashes. Hope helps))

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question and suggests fumbling around in source codes that are reverted by the next npm update ..